# How to use Ionic's RouterDirection with a click event?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When routing from one page to another, the firstly used technique is the **routerLink + routerDirection**. In the first piece of code (#1), we go from one page to next page with a direction of `forward`. When we want to  go back to the original page, in the second piece of code (#2), we have to pass data in the state of the router. So there we use a `click` event to handle the routing.

Problem occurs with the second navigation with the **click event** (#2). We lose the ability to trigger the routerDirection to use the `back` animation. The page is rampaging forward (see the example below #3).

Is there a way to trigger the `back` animation with **routerDirection + click** event?

Angular NavigationExtras don't provide this as I looked into the documention here:
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

**#1 | Route to page with routerLink**

```html
<ion-button fill="clear" routerLink="/chat-settings" routerDirection="forward">
  <ion-icon color="light" name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

**#2 | Route back with click event**

```html
<ion-button (click)="goToChat()" routerDirection="back"> <!-- routerDirection does nothing -->
  <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="close"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

```js
goToChat() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/chat/' + this.chatID, {
    state: {
      // ...
    },
  });
}
```

**#3 | Live device**

[image: animation on live device]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using NavController's `navigateBack()` function which uses `router.navigateByUrl()` under the hood [as you can see here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/src/providers/nav-controller.ts#L90). Your `goToChat()` function would then look something like this:

```
goToChat() {
  this.navController.navigateBack('/chat/' + this.chatID, {
    state: {
      // ...
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: I was under the impression that NavController is deprecated as in Ionic 4. As quoting from the link: "If migrating from Ionic 3, be aware that some familiar Ionic navigation elements have been deprecated in version 4. While they work, it is NOT recommended to use `NavController` or `ion-nav`. " https://fireship.io/lessons/ionic-4-routing-and-navigation-guide/